# Django - Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Here are my forms:

```
class RoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.RoleModel
        fields = ['name']

class FeatureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    role = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.RoleModel.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct())
    class Meta:
        model = models.FeatureModel
        fields = ['role','feature']
```

In my bootstrap form, the choices display properly. I get a list of all roles. But if I fill the feature form and hit submit it says - "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

My models are:

```
class RoleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)

class FeatureModel(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(RoleModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    feature = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=10, unique=True)
```

my bootsrtap form is:

```
<form action="{% url 'feature_form' %}" novalidate method="POST">{% csrf_token %}         
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <label for="role">{{ fform.role.label }}</label>
                <p><select class="form-control id="role" name="role">
                {% for item in fform.role %}
                {{ item }}
                {% endfor %}
                </select></p>
                {% for error in fform.role.errors %}
                <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                <label for="feature">{{ fform.feature.label }</label>
                <p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="feature" name="feature"
                {% if fform.feature.value is not None %}
                value="{{ fform.feature.value }}"
                {% endif %}
                ></p>
                {% for error in fform.feature.errors %}
                <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>

            <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' value='Save'>                
        </form>
```

My need is simple. The second form (FeatureForm) has two fields. role being foreign key of another model and a text field to type in name of a feature. On my client side, I need the foreign key to be displayed as a select option with a list. I chose a value from this select, enter the value of feature and hit save. It has to save.

[image: client side screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because your queryset includes only names, but you need an id / primary key of a `RoleModel`. Since your choices don't have an id, they aren't a valid choice.

Firstly, your RoleModel `name` is set to `unique` and is therefore no point in querying `distinct()` name values because they will be distinct already by unique definition.

You also don't need to construct your own select input. Django will take care of this.

All you need is:

```
class RoleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class FeatureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FeatureModel
        fields = ['role', 'feature']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FeatureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}
```

and

```
<form action="{% url 'feature_form' %}" novalidate method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}         
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="role">{{ fform.role.label }}</label>
            <p>{{ fform.role }} </p>
            {% for error in fform.role.errors %}
            <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="feature">{{ fform.feature.label }</label>
            <p>{{ fform.feature }}</p>
            {% for error in fform.feature.errors %}
            <p><small class="alert-danger">{{ error }}</small></p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' value='Save'>                
</form>
```

**EDIT:** Otherwise, a Select input in this case should be constructed as:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Name 2</option>
</select>
```

where `value` is an id, a primary key of `RoleModel` in your case. Your select options don't have this value.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This way it saves the data. However, in the select option at client side, I am not getting the value instead it displays as RoleModel object(3). How could we tweak this to get the select to display values instead of object?

Comment: Add __str__ to `RoleModel`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you. As for me to understand what does the __init__ function in feature form do exactly?

Comment: __init__ is meant to customize object instance to a specific initial state. In this case it is used to add attribute class to fields so you don't have to add form-control to each field separately in widgets Meta option or even with templatetags in template.