# Select a valid choice while selecting Foreignkey in django admin mongodb

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

database in MongoDB (djongo)

I have registered a model in admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Media)
```

models.py

```
class Media(BaseModel):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, db_column="post", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, db_column="group", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "media"
```

while changing values using the admin site I got these errors.
[image]

can you help me to solve this error?

django==3.0.5

djongo==1.3.4

Comment: Hello harshil Please check this stackoverflow case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041375/django-select-a-valid-choice-that-choice-is-not-one-of-the-available-choices)

Comment: I didn't use model forms in admin, I have worked with django admin many times but I think this error's cause is mongodb(djonog) @Hiren30598

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you try to save an instance of an object with **PK an ObjectId** that it is transformed into a **string** and consequently no longer corresponds to an instance of an object, so with the override of the **get_form** method in **POST** you can intercept this data and change the **string to ObjectId**, but as you can see in the [Django documentation][1]:

> The **QueryDicts** at **request.POST** and **request.GET** will be immutable when
> accessed in a normal request/response cycle.

so you can use the recommendation from the same documentation:

> To get a mutable version you need to use **QueryDict.copy()**

or ... use a little trick, for example, if you need to **keep a reference** to an object for some reason or leave the object the same:

```
# remember old state
_mutable = data._mutable

# set to mutable
data._mutable = True

# сhange the values you want
data['param_name'] = 'new value'

# set mutable flag back
data._mutable = _mutable
```

where data it is your **QueryDicts**

In this case:

```
@admin.register(MyMode)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('....')
    ....

    def get_form(self, request, obj, change, **kwargs):
        if request.POST:
            # remember old state
            _mutable = request.POST._mutable
            # set to mutable
            request.POST._mutable = True
            # сhange the values you want
            request.POST['user'] = ObjectId(request.POST['user'])
            request.POST['post'] = ObjectId(request.POST['post'])
            request.POST['group'] = ObjectId(request.POST['group'])
            # set mutable flag back
            request.POST._mutable = _mutable

        return super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Post edited with explanation